# Determining what the concurrency was from log files

Tags: logging

I have a set of log files (generated via log4j logging) that indicate the time (down to the millisecond) when the "transaction was completed" along with how long (in milliseconds) the transaction took. The application processes 50 - 100 transactions per second, but I am trying to graph out what the actual max concurrency was within a given time period.

Does anyone know of a tool, or simple process to be able to pull the end time and duration info into to generate a graph,or even a table of info>

Comment: Does each thread have some kind of unique ID that gets logged?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the platform you are on and your preferred tools ...

You can process you log files with unix tools, a little script, favorite text editor, excel and a database.

This is the variant I probably would use

- use `grep` to filter your file for the relevant lines
- use `cut` to separate the columns you need and to discard information you do not need.
- use `sed` to transform this into an insert script
- run it against an oracle XE database
- create a view transforming end time + duration into start time
- create a view transforming the table of start time and end times into a single time column and a column containing +1 for starttimes and -1 for end times
- create a view using analytic functions to create a number of running processes column by doing a running sum of the +-1 comlumn